# What is `Can't find variable: loadHomepageTiles` error on iOS 11.3

Tags: ios, ios11.3, ios11.4

I recently came across this error `message: Can't find variable: loadHomepageTiles` on our error logs from one of our angularjs 1.6 mobile applications.

This seems to only happen on iOS devices running 11.3 based on the error logs.

We don't have any reference to `loadHomepageTiles` on our codebase and I could not find any references to this in any of the node modules either so. It seems to be generated by mobile safari from what we can tell.

I can't seem to find any documentation about it on the net or how to recreate the error on an iOS device. Does anyone have any experience with this error? or could point me towards any documentation, please? thanks

Comment: How did you track it down to mobile Safari? Any details?

Comment: Nothing yet - i'll post back here if we find anything.

Comment: Do you have a mapbox or anything that uses canvas? Might be google maps/streetview? I have the same issue.

Comment: We do have google maps on our application. Thanks for letting me know I'll investigate. If I find anything - I'll post back here.

Comment: Anything on this ?

Comment: Nothing yet I am afraid. We are still looking into this on our side. I will post here if we find anything.

Comment: I have the same error today. And I don't have any maps on my site. Additional info: browser = Mobile Safari UIWebView 12.0  and here its iOS 12 and a React  application

Comment: I just got this for an iOS 12.1 iPhone.. the last thing that was released before was some browser detection using _bowser_..

Comment: I am curious if anyone else sees `ManagedBrowser` in the User Agent when this error occurs. I think this may just be an enterprise restricted phone browser where a function to detect if an application is already installed on the homescreen is restricted. Our sentry log records the error occurring in global code at 1:18, which is either inside a html tag, or inside the text `window["webpackJsonp"]`. I am pretty sure the error occurs in browser code instead.

Comment: @Sumurai8, yes, I am too seeing `ManagedBrowser/20181024.1` as part of the User Agent. Very interesting, I wonder if it affects our application as seen by the user.

Comment: Our Sentry logs just started showing this error as well. I presume this is not coming from our codebase since it's reported to occur in the first line of html.
Some log details:
browser: Mobile Safari UI/WKWebView 12.2 | 
browser.name: Mobile Safari UI/WKWebView | 
device: iPhone | 
os: iOS 12.2

Comment: I have been getting similar error logs as late as today: ` "userAgent": "Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 13_1_3 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Mobile/15E148 ManagedBrowser/20181024.1"`

Comment: I think it could be a missing polyfill for ManagedBrowser.  See the following issue which is a different issue, but a similar kind of problem https://github.com/Financial-Times/polyfill-library/issues/302. Hopefully another stack overflow engineer can assist in figuring out the specific polyfill that would be needed.